# How to set ASP.NET session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am new to ASP.NET and I am trying to set session variable. I have one form (SelectPlayer.aspx) where I am trying to set the session but when I try to see the result on second page it does not show me any value. Below is my code.

SelectPlayer.aspx

```
public partial class SelectPlayer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["player1"] == null)
        {   
            lblSelectPlayer.Text = "Select Player 1";
        }
    }

    protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Session["player1"] = "PlayerSession";                
        Response.Redirect("Score.aspx");          
    }

}
```

Score.aspx

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["player1"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("SelectPlayer.aspx");
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Try Response.Redirect("Score.aspx", false), Since true is default option and throws exception in some case. Check :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: same result with false

Comment: What is the mode you have used in Web.config (e.g. <sessionState mode="InProc" />)

Answer (score -2):

Change `Response.Redirect("Score.aspx");` to `Response.Redirect("Score.aspx", true);`

The second parameter of a redirect indicates that you want to end the response. I've found in the past that setting a Session directly before doing a redirect without this second parameter can cause issues.

Comment: same result i am getting null on second page

Comment: Can you post the relevant code from your second page, `Score.aspx`?